# Can I use my Android device to find out which FM frequency has the least noise?

Tags: fm-radio

I have an Android device (Nougat) with a built in FM reciever.

I also have an FM transmitter that I use to transmit audio to my car stereo. As I travel around, I find that the landscape of FM real radio 
transmissions differs. I want to be on the frequency  with the least noise (regular transmissions) so that I can get the least disturbance for my own signal.

There are some services where I could look this up online, or I could just do it by trial and error, but as I travel around this gets inconvenient.

I know that dedicated hardware exits to automatically find the FM frequency with the least noise with one click, but I figure my phone already has the hardware to do it. Can I do it with my Android phone?

I have root and Xposed Framework, if it matters.

Comment: It is simply an FM tuner with simple controls (frequency and audio output) to the phone... The chipset is very dumb, there isn't much you or an app can do with it except set a frequency and listen to FM radio. I guess you could plug in headphones and sweep through the frequencies listening for a clear one, but otherwise it's just trial and error. I would put this as an answer but I cannot find definitive information to confirm or detract from my statements.

Comment: @acejavelin Couldn't an app automatically sweep through the frequencies and find where the largest gap is with no transmissions? I guess an app would be able to differentiate between voice/music and lack of transmissions.

Comment: I don't know how the audio is handled... Possibly. Sounds like a lot of work for minimal return.

Comment: Old post: https://github.com/mikereidis/androidfm/wiki/Creating-an-Android-FM-app but if you are a developer it looks complicated & if you aren't a developer it looks complicated.